# Can a pronoun refer to a subject in the next clause?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

**Is it grammatically correct to have a pronoun refer to a subject in the next clause? See the below example.**

> Because **their** guardians are with **them**, **teenagers** will not
> be able to approach drug dealers to buy illegal substances.

**What is this called?**

Comment: I am sure that in your language, it's the same thing. Please post examples to illustrate rather than just dry grammar points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is grammatically correct. When the pronoun follows its antecedent, it is called **anaphoric**. When the pronoun precedes its antecedent, it is called **cataphoric**.
See this link
[grammar.com "antecedents"](https://www.grammar.com/antecedents-placement-of-pronouns/)

"... a cataphoric (forward-looking) pronoun would find its referent coming later in the sentence:
After his discovery of New Zealand, Captain Cook went on to discover several Pacific islands. (This example appears in New Fowler, p. 134.)